# django updating user profile form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

## forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length = 15,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs = {'placeholder':'Enter mobile no. ','class':''}))
    profession = forms.CharField(max_length= 50,widget = forms.Select(choices = PROFESSION_CHOICES,attrs = {'class':''}))
    #email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address',max_length = 75,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Email address.','class':''}))
    sex = forms.CharField(max_length = 20,label="I am :",widget=forms.Select(choices=SEX_CHOICES,attrs = {'class':''}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Please enter your real name.','class':''}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter last name.','class':''}))
    location = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Enter your current location','class':''}))
    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        if first_name == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("This field is required.")
        return first_name

        def save(self,*args,**kw):
                    self.instance.first_name = self.cleaned_data.get("first_name")
                    self.instance.last_name = self.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
                    self.instance.sex = self.cleaned_data.get("sex")
                    self.instance.location = self.cleaned_data.get("location")
                    self.instance.profession = self.cleaned_data.get("profession")
                    self.instance.phone = self.cleaned_data.get("phone")
                    self.instance.save()
                    return self.instance





    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','phone','sex','profession','location')
```

## views.py

```
def profile(request,nav="profile",template="profile.html",context = {},extra_context = None):
    if request.POST:
        if 'profileFormSubmit' in request.POST:
            pform = UserProfileForm(request.POST,instance = request.user)
            if pform.is_valid():
                try:
                    user = pform.save()
                    return redirect(profile,nav="profile")
                    except RuntimeError as e:
                    return HttpResponse(e)
```

## error

```
The User could not be changed because the data didn't validate.
```

## line

```
    user = super(UserProfileForm,self).save(*args,**kw)
```

## doubt

what changes am i supposed to make to get rid of this error
how am i supposed to change the  , i have tried removing all the clean_field form methods , but still getting the same error , please help , thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form wasn't validating because I was using 'username' in my meta class of the UserProfileForm, which wasn't supposed to be there.

Comment: Accept your answer so the question will not remain open.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling save on your form before you clean. And you are calling save twice. Once at the start of the form save. And once at the end.

pform.is_valid() returns a boolean that you never check.

[docs on modelforms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: i have changed it a bit , but still i am getting the error that UserProfileForm doesnt have a cleaned_data attribute

Comment: cleaned_data wont exist until after you validate the form. You either have to check is_valid, or directly call the clean method. Basically you are breaking the save method by not having it clean first.

Comment: i have individually cleaned all the fields such as clean_first_name...etc. , but still i am getting the same error

Comment: Which error? You mentioned a new missing attribute error. Are you sure your is_valid() is returning True before calling save? Maybe you have a non null field that isnt being set.

Comment: yes every thing is working fine now , the only problem was that , the username field was there  ,and i wasnt validating with the username and username is not supposed to be edited so i removed it from the fields inside the meta class so its working fine now